# virtual host with aws private IP address

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip-address, virtualhost

Can anyone explain exactly how AWS internal/private IPs work? (in regards to binding them with elastic IPs).

For instance, say I have an AWS Virtual Private Server that is using SSL..

elastic IP 54.1.1.1 (bound to internal IP 10.1.1.1)

If I hit https://54.1.1.1 it works perfectly with this configuration..

```
<VirtualHost 10.1.1.1:443>
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite
       ServerName mysite.com    
       ServerAlias mysite.com 
</VirtualHost>
```

However, I have another server not hosted with AWS.
When I try to do this same thing, it does not see the above configuration.

Is there something AWS does that allows apache to know that elastic IP 54.1.1.1 is equivalent to 10.1.1.1?

Answer (score 1):

You might find this [documentation of Elastic IP's](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) helpful.

> We assign each instance in a default VPC two IP addresses at launch: a
>   private IP address and a public IP address that is mapped to the
>   private IP address through network address translation (NAT). The
>   public IP address is allocated from the EC2-VPC public IP address
>   pool, and is associated with your instance, not with your AWS account.
>   You cannot reuse a public IP address after it's been disassociated
>   from your instance.

Comment: thanks. so regarding how apache works (on a non aws server), when it receives a request from a public IP, that public IP has no relation to any internal IP that the server may have, correct?

Comment: That is correct. On normal servers the NIC is typically assigned the Public IP which Apache listens on so the request will be routed directly to that. Apache can also listen on internal IP's too much, no typically there is no relation.